# python + selenium - focus to make infinite scroll load

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am scraping a limited number of items from the top of an infinite-scroll website.

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='fixed-recipe-card__info']//a")
while len(links)<100:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='fixed-recipe-card__info']//a")
```

This works wonderfully when the window is active. However, if I have the test browser minimized, the new content does not load and the loop runs infinitely. I'm rather new to selenium, so I'm not quite sure why. I suspect there is a Javascript onChange that isn't being triggered. Is there a javascript command I should add to my script, or another selenium command that will cause the new content to load?

I am using Python 2.7, selenium with Chromedriver. An example site is [allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com/recipes/276/desserts/cakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you minimize it because you are busy with other things? You can use headless mode once your code is doing what you want visually and avoid this problem.

Comment: Headless is exactly what I didn't know I needed, thanks!

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: @Dev_Man Googling "python selenium headless Chrome" should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you should try PhantomJs as the driver if minimizing the window is a big concern. It basically works the same way as the chrome driver but it uses no browser so all your code will run in the backgroud, it worked for me. It may work for you, happy coding! http://phantomjs.org

Comment: Phantomjs is no longer actively maintained, as Google released Chrome with headless capability and Phantomjs's head stepped away from the project.

For scraping, it may still work for the near future, but for automated testing and for continued compatibility, it is better to use a browser the end user is actually using (chrome) as opposed to something no end user is browsing on (phantomjs).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *the test browser minimized, the new content does not load* is pretty much expected as *Selenium needs **focus** on the **Browsing Window** to interact with the DOM elements.*

### Reason

At this point it is worth to mention that *a webpage could **change its content** when the **focus is lost*** . You need to consider the fact *Selenium was mainly designed for testing*.

### Solution

Ideally, ***Automated Test Execution*** or ***Web Scraping*** must be performed within an isolated ***Test Environment*** preferably in a ***Test Lab*** configured with the required *Hardware* and *Software* configuration which must be free from ***Manual Intervention***.

Comment: Nowhere in the question did OP say they were performing automated testing. They mentioned they are scraping, and since most home users don't have an isolated environment handy, I don't see how your answer addresses the question.